# What does this road sign mean?

Tags: uk

I regularly pass a (UK) road sign that I don't recognise.

[image]

My gut instinct is that it's warning me about a bridge or a tunnel but it's on a [normal dual-carriageway](https://www.google.com/maps/@53.789653,-1.6109152,3a,19.4y,129.27h,90.63t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sOjyOVE8XWBTe6d8osZ9eEg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) and there are no obvious overhead structures for more than a mile, nor are there any side turnings that it seems to relate to.

**So what the heck is it and what am I supposed to be looking out for?**

Comment: For the record, it's not in the DVLA "[Know your traffic signs](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/222621/dg_191955.pdf)" book;

Comment: Looks like dowsing rods crossing...maybe underground water?  It's be weird though considering dowsing is completely pseudoscience.

Comment: Looking at the book, it looks like some munged form of the "humped roadway" signs.  Does the particular stretch of road have a high point?

Comment: @ChrisinAK - Nope, flat and level with a *very* slight curve to the right. But  absolutely no humps or obstructions.

Comment: Something like a deer crossing or tractor crossing warning??

Comment: Would it be an arch bridge sign like the one on page 24 of the "know your traffic signs" ebook?https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/222621/dg_191955.pdf

Comment: After some consideration, I've decided that it's probably a warning sign that people might be turning to come back the other way along the dual carriageway ahead. The presence of an arrow on the right-hand side of the sign shows the (possible) direction of traffic. I've posted a bounty for anyone who can get actual confirmation (e.g. not just speculation)

Comment: Sure looks like some sort of "U-turn allowed" sign to me.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - It's a lot easier to identify when it's static than when you're chugging past it at 50MPH :-)

Comment: Excellent point raised in flags - what is the relevance of this question to bicycles?  Does this sign have relevance to a cycle lane or path?  Are bicycles permitted on this road?    Argenti's answer suggests it might be a sign found on motorways (A roads), where bicycles are not permitted.

Comment: @Criggie - **Highway Code: Rule 69** - Cyclists MUST obey all traffic signs and traffic light signals. / **Highway Code: Rule 253** - Prohibited vehicles. Motorways MUST NOT be used by ...  cyclists.

Comment: @Criggie - Whoever flagged this is simply incorrect. Cycles are allowed on all UK roads *other than motorways*. A-roads (which are typically dual carriageways) are not motorways, hence cyclists can use them and must obey the signs found on them.

Comment: @richard - all good, thank you for the clarification.   I was under the impression an A road was a motorway, and the pictures in the answer didn't show an outside white line or any form of shoulder.  Second pic shows a pathway but not labelled as a cycle lane, hence why I asked.

Comment: @Criggie - That pathway is a pavement. Most UK cyclists seem to treat them like cycle paths

Comment: @Richard don't mention pavement - the Americans will get all excited again :P (footpath, sidewalk etc. etc)

Comment: Its for budding rally drivers indicating handbrake turn ahead!

Answer (score 15):

The 'arch' is actually an arrow - look at the right hand end.

I believe it means there is a junction between the carriageways that allows you to make a right turn and travel along the opposite side.

[image]

There's another sign on the other side of the carriageway, and a corresponding u-turn junction.

[image]

Comment: Although this is likely to be true, I've reserved the bounty for an answer that offers specific confirmation

Comment: Two photos are about the same place but from opposite directions ?  So is the sign warning that a motorist CAN turn here to go the other way, or that the other side of the road has a U turn option here and could appear in the green-middle of the road where there are no joining roads ?

Comment: This seems likely tho I can’t verify either. I think the implication is that a car making a u-turn must cross fully through the central reservation to complete the manoeuvre.

Comment: It's definitely indicating that this is a place to do U-turns but I can't find any official (or even unofficial) confirmation of that, anywhere.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - It's a weird one and one that I've not seen before. I've messaged the Highways Agency for specific confirmation (since they're nominally in charge of all road signage) but they've not come back to me, yet.

Comment: I asked an expert on Twitter and got the reply: "This is a non-prescribed road sign showing a U-turn in the central reservation of the A6110. It's modelled on the 1975 contraflow sign but is meaningless to most drivers." https://twitter.com/ShowMeASignBryn/status/1099595986610073600

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen - I can see the similarity; https://www.sabre-roads.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?t=36808

Comment: It's an "n" turn sign :) They're like U turns but the other way up.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a low bridge / arch bridge warning. Strange, they usually have text indicating the minimum height.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ukmotorists.com](http://www.ukmotorists.com/signs/5h.jpg))</sub>

Note that this is a **wrong answer** but keeping it here so other people can know it’s not a low bridge sign. Feel free to downvote.

Comment: @RoboKaren fair play, worth keeping - otherwise someone will come along and suggest it's a bridge again lol

Comment: Well, I've undone my downvote as I agree that "It's not a low bridge" is a useful answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby hey, I’m asking you to downvote me. :)